# How to calculate the ccf (cross-correlation) function mannually when one time series contains NA in R?

Tags: r, time-series, statistical-significance, autocorrelation, cross-correlation

I have two time series, for example:

```
a = c(2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
b = c(NA, NA, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1)
ccf(a, b, na.action=na.omit, plot=FALSE)
```

The results of ccf shows the following:

```
Autocorrelations of series ‘X’, by lag

    -3     -2     -1      0      1      2      3 
 0.400 -0.567  0.800 -1.000  0.800 -0.567  0.400
```

When lag equals 0, the ccf values is -1. However, I can't figure out why the value is 0.8 (lag = -1) and -0.567 (lag = -2).

I've read the link from [Why do I get different results using ccf() and cor() in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399788/why-do-i-get-different-results-using-ccf-and-cor-in-r). But it is based on acf and doesn't contains  NAs.

How to calculate it when it contains NA?

Specifically, what is the formula when calculate when lag = -2 in this toy example ?

Answer (score 3):

As the simple correlation coefficient between the lagged series from the sample gives biased estimation of the population correlation coefficient $\rho_{ij} \left( t \right)$, an unbiased estimator should be applied.

If you take a look at the built in help (`?ccf`), there is a reference there to the book *Venables, W. N. and Ripley, B. D. (2002): Modern Applied Statistics with S.  Fourth Edition.  Springer-Verlag.* On page 390 you can find the estimation formula for `ccf`:

$$c_{ij}\left( t \right) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{s = \max \left( 1, -t \right)}^{\min\left( n - t, n \right)}{\left( X_i \left( s + t \right) - \overline{X_i} \right) \left( X_j\left( s \right) - \overline{X_j} \right)}, \qquad r_{ij}\left( t \right) = \frac{c_{ij}\left( t \right)}{\left| c_{ij}\left( 0 \right) \right|}$$

(Actually $r_{ij} \left( t \right)$ is not there, but it can be easily deducted from `acf` functions $r_t$. The latter is $r_t = \frac{c_t}{c_0}$ there, without the absolute value in the denominator, as $c_0$ is always positive in case of `acf`, but it is obviously needed in case of `ccf` (think about $r_{ij} \left( 0 \right) = -1$ as the case with `a` and `b` in this question).

As

```
a <- c(2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
b <- c(NA, NA, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1)
ccf(a, b, na.action=na.omit, plot=FALSE)
```

is equivalent with

```
a <- c(2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
b <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1)
ccf(a, b, plot=FALSE)
```

with the result

```
Autocorrelations of series ‘X’, by lag

    -3     -2     -1      0      1      2      3 
 0.400 -0.567  0.800 -1.000  0.800 -0.567  0.400
```

you can check the calculations applying the above formulas 'manually' with the next `R` code:

```
a <- c(2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
b <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1)
n <- length(a)
c_0 <- abs(1 / n * sum((a - mean(a)) * (b - mean(b))))
for (t in -3:3) {
  if (t <= 0) {
    c_t <- 1 / n * sum((a[1:(n + t)] - mean(a)) * (b[(1 - t):n] - mean(b)))
  } else {
    c_t <- 1 / n * sum((a[(1 + t):n] - mean(a)) * (b[1:(n - t)] - mean(b)))
  }
  r_t <- c_t / c_0
  print(r_t)
}
```

with results

```
[1] 0.4
[1] -0.5666667
[1] 0.8
[1] -1
[1] 0.8
[1] -0.5666667
[1] 0.4
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I still have two questions. (1) How to calculate when using  `na.action = na.pass` in ccf in this toy example? According to your answer, na.omit ignore the information of the first two value in a. When using `ccf(a, b, na.action=na.pass, plot=FALSE)` , the ccf returns -0.99 (lag = 0), 0.825 (lag = -1).  (2) Why does the simple correlation coefficient between the lagged series from the sample give biased estimation of the population correlation coefficient ?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think these are separate questions, so it is not the best idea to discuss them in the comments, but some quick hints: (1) from `ccf` help using `na.pass` "*means that the estimate computed may well not be a valid autocorrelation sequence, and may contain missing values*". So I think it's better to omit `NA`s. To get more insight, I think you have to check the source code of `ccf`. (2) Check this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220961/is-the-sample-correlation-coefficient-an-unbiased-estimator-of-the-population-co

Answer (score 3):

There may be a mistake in the formula from @oszkar's answer. You can see this by modifying `b` from the example above. The code

```
a <- c(2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
b <- c(1, 2, -1, -2, 1)
n <- length(a)
c_0 <- abs(1 / n * sum((a - mean(a)) * (b - mean(b))))
for (t in -3:3) {
    if (t <= 0) {
        c_t <- 1 / n * sum((a[1:(n + t)] - mean(a)) * (b[(1 - t):n] - mean(b)))
    } else {
        c_t <- 1 / n * sum((a[(1 + t):n] - mean(a)) * (b[1:(n - t)] - mean(b)))
    }
    r_t <- c_t / c_0
    print(r_t)
}
```

yields

```
[1] -3.4
[1] 2.9
[1] 0.2
[1] 1
[1] 0.2
[1] -3.1
[1] 0.6
```

It may not make sense to have a correlation outside of [-1, 1]. The `ccf` in R:

```
ccf(a, b, 3, plot = F)$acf
```

gives

```
, , 1

            [,1]
[1,] -0.37777778
[2,]  0.32222222
[3,]  0.02222222
[4,]  0.11111111
[5,]  0.02222222
[6,] -0.34444444
[7,]  0.06666667
```

The form for $r_{ij}(t)$ used in R is actually
$$r_{ij}(t)=\dfrac{c_{ij}(t)}{\sqrt{\sigma_i^2\sigma_j^2}}$$
where
$$\sigma_i^2=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{s=1}^{n}\left[X_i(s)-\overline{X}_i\right]^2.$$
That is, the denominator is the square root of the product of the "population variance" of the two time series. With this formula you can see that the results below match with the results from `ccf`.

```
a <- c(2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
b <- c(1, 2, -1, -2, 1)
n <- length(a)
c_0 <- sqrt(sum((a - mean(a)) ^ 2 / n) * sum((b - mean(b)) ^ 2 / n))
for (t in -3:3) {
    if (t <= 0) {
        c_t <- 1 / n * sum((a[1:(n + t)] - mean(a)) * (b[(1 - t):n] - mean(b)))
    } else {
        c_t <- 1 / n * sum((a[(1 + t):n] - mean(a)) * (b[1:(n - t)] - mean(b)))
    }
    r_t <- c_t / c_0
    print(r_t)
}
```

gives

```
[1] -0.3777778
[1] 0.3222222
[1] 0.02222222
[1] 0.1111111
[1] 0.02222222
[1] -0.3444444
[1] 0.06666667
```

Comment: This is a good observation -- but please don't leap to the conclusion that the other answer has a mistake.  There is more than one way to define the ccf.  This is analogous to different perspectives on the acf, as I explain at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/81764/919.  If the series is so short that different formulas give appreciably different results, then it's probably too short to be relying on *any* of those formulas!

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the message! I understand that there might be different formulas for the ccf with different perspectives. But the formula **oszakr** used can produce cross-correlation outside [-1, 1], so I have modified my answer to reflect on this.