# Why the sample covariance estimator is unbiased, but the sample pearson correlation coeficient is not?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, correlation, covariance, unbiased-estimator

Why the sample covariance estimator [is unbiased](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_mean_and_covariance), but the sample Pearson correlation coefficient [is not](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220961/is-the-sample-correlation-coefficient-an-unbiased-estimator-of-the-population-co)?

I'm a bit confused because the sample Pearson coefficent was built using the sample covariance estimator and the sample variance estimator, that are both unbiased.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Amazingly, transforming an unbiased estimator often results in a biased estimator. This is how the sample standard deviation is a biased estimator, despite the sample variance being unbiased. This fact comes from something called Jensen’s inequality. For a concave function $f$, such as a square root:

$$
f(\mathbb{E}[X])\ge \mathbb{E}[f(X)]
$$

Equality holds if and only if $f$ is a straight line (or if $X$ is constant).

So why is $\hat{\rho}=\dfrac{\widehat{cov}(X,Y)}{s_X s_Y}$ biased? The standard deviation estimators are biased!

Comment: The Wikipedia article on Jensen’s inequality has some pictures that might give some intuition.