# What is the sampling bias in sample Pearson correlation coefficient squared?

Tags: correlation, sampling, bias

Suppose $r$ is the sample Pearson correlation coefficient estimator of two random variables $X$ and $Y$, while $rho$ is the population correlation coefficient. From various sources, e.g., [Is the sample correlation coefficient an unbiased estimator of the population correlation coefficient?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220961/is-the-sample-correlation-coefficient-an-unbiased-estimator-of-the-population-co), we know that, if $X$ and $Y$ obey the bi-variate Gaussian random variables with population correlation coefficient $\rho$, the bias of the sample estimator is
$$
E[r]=\rho\left[ 1-\dfrac{1-\rho^2}{2N}+O(1/N^2) \right].
$$
Then what is the sampling bias of the estimator $r^2$?